# Does uniform convergence of a series implies pointwise *absolutely* convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Assume we have a series of functions which converge uniformly on a closed interval. Does that implies absolutely convergence (pointwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take any real sequence $a_n$ s.t. $\sum_n a_n$ converges, but does not converge absolutely (e.g. $a_n=(-1)^n 1/n$). Then consider $f_n(x) := a_n$. Obviously, the convergence is uniform in $x$, because nothing depends on $x$.